# Was für ein schöner Tag! vs Welch ein schöner Tag! - exclamation

Tags: spoken-language, written-language

Would you say there is a difference between *was für ein* vs *welch* when you want to express amazement / surprise?

In written German is it preferred to use *Welch ein schöner Tag!* and in spoken language *Was für ein schöner Tag?*

Comment: Yes, there is a slight difference in register, I'd consider _welch_ more formal; old-fashioned even. That said, and even tough I cannot explain it, I would leave out the article with welch, i.e. _Welch schöner Tag_.

Answer (score 2):

> Welch schöner Tag

would be considered (becoming) archaic and somewhat elevated speech. It is definitely not for everyday usage.

Answer (score 2):

That are two questions.

> Would you say there is a difference between *was für ein* vs *welch ein* when you want to express amazement / surprise?

There is a difference. But I think almost nobody will notice and maybe at least some will disagree and call it bean-counting. *Welche* is asking for characteristics. *Welche Eigenschaften?* - *What attributes?*

*Was für* is kind of asking for a purpose since *wofür (für)* is asking for a purpose. *Was für* and *wofür* is not the same - of course. One is a statement and the other one a question. But *für* clearly points to a purpose.

> In written German is it preferred to use *Welch ein schöner Tag!* and in spoken language *Was für ein schöner Tag!*?

That's a question of *who preferres what* and not really about written or spoken language.

Some might say, that using *welch ein* is elevated speech - even in written language. Some might say using *was für* is colloquial language.

It's not a big deal, so I think you should use what feels good taking into account what I said so far.

I disagree that *welche* wouldn't be for everyday usage. I would definitely prefer *welche* over *was für*. But that's just because I don't think that a beautiful day needs to have a purpose and (for me) it feels better to keep that in mind. You have to consider, that people in Germany are very shy if it comes to sounding *elevated* if they don't feel elevated (for a good reason). But that doesn't mean that they would consider you snobby just because you prefer *welch ein* over *was für ein* if it's not for just sounding elevated. ;)